# How to get name of the bit field referenced by BIT_FIELD_REF?

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, internal

I want to get the name of the field with which it was declared from GENERIC representation. I have a BIT_FIELD_REF tree and it's DECL_NAME is zero. For example,

```
struct {
    int a;
    unsigned b:1;
} s;

...
if (s.b)
    ...
```

For s.b I'll get a BIT_FIELD_REF and there's no obvious way to get the “b”, which is the original name of the field. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `call debug_c_tree (tree_var)` or `call debug_tree (tree_var)` from GDB, and see if that knows the name. If it does, reverse engineer the pretty-printer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't know the name.

Any other way to do it?

Comment: Sorry, if it's knowable, I'd expect the pretty-printer to print it. Does it reappear in later dump files? tree-ssa passes maybe? I'd guess so, and they'd need to get it from somewhere.

Comment: problem is, they really know and print in dumps names of __some__ bitfields (not all, and the particular case I was interested in initially didn't output it's name)
I think I'll try to determine where does it get the name when it does, but I'm not sure where's it gets printed out.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly did I do: investigating stuff in `tree-dump.c` I ended up understanding that names of the bit fields where they're known were coming from struct's DIEs and were hard to track.

Then I decided to get the name from the `BIT_FIELD_REF` argument 0 (reference to structure) type, which is `RECORD_TYPE` and it stores all the fields' sizes and offsets.

Problem was to understand that `BIT_FIELD_REF` doesn't reference the bits itself: it is used like `BIT_FIELD_REF & INTEGER_CST`, where constant acts like mask. After understanding this, I quickly computed the offsets and got the name from the type.